# Regular expression to match a united states phone pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a United States phone number, this is what I have so far:

```
var numberRegex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/
```

My problem with this is that this allows single bracket.

This will allow to pass an opening parenthesis without a closing one like this: `(111-121-1212`.

Does anyone have a regex script that will match a U.S phone number and account for brackets?

Comment: instead of throwing an error fix it

Comment: It is not throwing an error. It is just validating a wrong input

Comment: @FaizanAli epascarello is suggesting that you simply add the missing ")" using code instead of stopping submit. not that I agree, just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternatives (`|`):

```
(?:
 \(([0-9]{3})\)
  |
 ([0-9]{3})
)
```

Resulting re looks like:

```
var numberRegex = /^(?:\(([0-9]{3})\)|([0-9]{3}))[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

[RegExLib might have your solution](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?categoryId=7&cattabindex=6&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score -1):

I would advise against this. The only way to validate a phone number is too try and call it and see who picks up. A phone number may look syntactically correct, but it can still be semantically wrong (ie. a fake phone number).

The best you can do is give the user a warning that the phone-number "doesn't look valid" but accept any input anyway.

Comment: This is a fair point, however it is reasonable to want to check the grammar and syntax of a number without the certainty that, necessarily, someone might actually answer the call. (I didn't downvote it, by the way).

Comment: not allowing phone numbers like "1234" I'm sure couldn't hurt the success rate. aside from that, this does not answer the question and is better suited for the notes section.

Comment: That's why I said "show a warning but allow all input". We're talking user friendly-ness here, this is why bank-account numbers have built in parity, but you might, for instance accidentally enter your address in the phone-number field (it happens!). I'm curious as to why this earned a downvote, feel free to comment Anonymous Coward.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen as I mentioned, this would then fill up your database with "1234"s, reducing your success rate. I know if I wanted to skip a registration field that wants a phone number, a warning that still allows me to still enter a bogus phone number would not stop me from entering a bogus phone number.

Comment: How would you propose you completely avoid 'fake' phonenumbers then? If having a valid phonenumber is important to your business then you should find other means to coerce your users into giving it to you. Like, asking nicely for instance or giving a good indication as to what format you expect.